# styling rails form_tag in css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, styling

I have a `form_tag` where I want to style the field tags and the borders around the field tag. this is my code so far:(I'm really new to rails btw)

```
<div class="login">
<%= form_tag("/login", method: "post") do %>   
  <%= label_tag(:email) %>   
  <%= email_field_tag(:email) %>
  <%= label_tag(:password) %>   
  <%= password_field_tag(:password) %>
 <%= submit_tag("Log In") %> 
<% end %>
```

```
css code: 
.login {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 450px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The docs for [form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) show that it takes an options hash as its second argument. Any provided option not listed in the docs will create a standard HTML attribute for the tag.

Give this a try:

```
<%= form_tag("/login", method: "post", class: "my_class") do %>
```